# What is the difference among RGBA_8888, TRANSPARENT, TRANSLUCENT in Android PixelFormat?

Tags: android, pixel, transparent, rgba, pixelformat

In android api document, I only get statements on TRANSPARENT and TRANSLUCENT, and there is nothing about RGBA_8888, so I feel totally confused by them.

TRANSLUCENT:System chooses a format that supports translucency (many alpha bits)
TRANSPARENT:System chooses a format that supports transparency (at least 1 alpha bit)

What are the actual differences when I using these 3 kinds of Format(Actually I can't figure out any difference when I using the function setFormat() on a view)?

Answer (score 3):

RGBA_8888 is an actual format.  Each pixel is 4 bytes, with 8 bits of red, green, blue, and transparency information.

The other two are used when specifying a type of format to use, but not an actual format.  TRANSPARENT means there there must be at least 1 alpha bit, but that whatever format is chosen doesn't need to support full blending-  it just needs to be able to be transparent or non-transparent.  For example, a JPEG has transparency.  TRANSLUCENT means it can be partially transparent and should have alpha blending applied.  RGBA_8888 is translucent, the alpha channel describes how to blend it in.  Translucency is a superset of transparency.

Comment: So, what's the difference between an actual format and a non-actual format.

Comment: A format describes a set series of bytes to describe each pixel.  A non-format is used by several functions to pick a format, its used to describe formats.  You need an actual format to draw.

Comment: Do you know what the mechanism that how android picks an actual format when using a non-format is?